# Where to put add_action php code to hook to Ninja Forms

Tags: php, ninja-forms

I want to add some code to process post ninja form submit, sth like this..
add_action( 'ninja_forms_post_process', 'my_ninja_forms_post_process', 1);

Where to put this code OR if making new file then where to put the new php file ?

Answer (score -1):

you can do it in the theme folder, under functions.php or (better way to handle scripts) you can use a script manager like this one
https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/

Comment: Why not show code instead of plugin? The idea is add code, not more plugins.